# Can we plaster our ceiling without removing the crown molding

Tags: ceiling, trim, plaster

We have removed popcorn from the ceiling and it now needs to be plastered. The crown molding in place is in perfect condition and we would like to leave it. Will it be possible to plaster the ceiling without the mounding getting messed up? Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to tell; would you please add a picture of the joint between the ceiling and the molding to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is more likely the crown molding would be damaged by removing it to refinish the ceiling than by leaving it in place (see [Should I remove moulding before adding a plaster ceiling?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/76639/should-i-remove-moulding-before-adding-a-plaster-ceiling?rq=1) and [Can I install drywall on the ceiling, without removing crown molding?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20337/can-i-install-drywall-on-the-ceiling-without-removing-crown-molding?rq=1))
It's fairly easy to leave it and tape off (or tape-and-plastic) to protect the molding while refinishing the ceiling.

Comment: Hi Fredric, should you have voted to close it as a duplicate  instead?

Answer (score -1):

No tear the celling down crown molding and walls do a whole gut of baseboreds electrical etc. Because plastering the celling would cause the other stuff to go off level